# how to get value from a field and store them in a variable

Tags: java, selenium, field, store

I have a field whose name and ID both are "TxtVAcc". I want to take the value in it (which is a 5 digit number) and store it in a variable say "AccNo".

And then pass its variable in a field which has the ID:
    ctl00_CP1_UcAddEditAppointments1_txtAccNumber

Right now I am using the following code and giving a hard coded value in the above field:

```
idriver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_CP1_UcAddEditAppointments1_txtAccNumber")).sendKeys(new String[] {"66495"});
```

I am using Selenium , JAva, Win 8, IE 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getAttribute("value") or getText() on a WebElement to access it's value:

```
String accNo = idriver.findElement(By.id("TxtVAcc")).getAttribute("value");
idriver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_CP1_UcAddEditAppointments1_txtAccNumber")).sendKeys(accNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download an add-on called Stored variables if you are using Selenium Ide in Firefox 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stored-variables-viewer-seleni/
Then save the variable and export the code

Comment: I am using Selenium , JAva, IE 10.

Comment: OK then my answer is not suitable for you.Look for add ons like Stored Variables in IE